# C - Rewriting a while-loop in a for-loop with if statements

Tags: c, for-loop, kernighan-and-ritchie

**--beware of horrible newbie code ahead--**

I'm trying to rewrite this simple counting program from `while` to `for`.

```
int c, nc;

nc = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c != '\n')
        ++nc;
    }
}
printf("%d\n", nc);
```

this outputs `example->8`.

so far I tried this couple of examples:

```
int c, nc;
for (nc = 0; ((c = getchar()) != EOF && (c = getchar()) != '\n'); ++nc)
    ;
printf("%d", nc);
```

and

```
int nc;
for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
    if (getchar() == '\n')
        --nc;
printf("%d", nc);
```

both this attempts lead to strange output like `example->3` or `a->0`, also the program doesn't "wait" anymore for a break after receiving its input, it just shows the output and close itself.

I would like to know what's happening here, because as I see it I just inserted (quite clumsily.. ) an `if` check and can't seem to explain what's happening..

Comment: Both of your `for` loops calls `getchar()` twice which causes each check to be performed only on every other character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `getchar()` twice

```
for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
    if (getchar() == '\n')
        --nc;
printf("%d", nc);
```

try this instead

```
int chr;
int nc;

chr = fgetc(stdin);
for (nc = 0 ; chr != EOF ; nc += (chr == '\n') ? 0 : 1)
    chr = fgetc(stdin);
printf("%d\n", nc);
```

`getchar()` which is equivalent to `fgetc(stdin)` reads a character from the input stream `stdin`, once you read that character you have to process it because it's removed from the stream, so calling the function twice will remove two characters from `stdin` and hence your count will be wrong.

So it doesn't matter how you write the for loop, what is important is to call `getchar()` once per iteration, for example this could work

```
int chr;
int nc;

for (nc = 0 ; ((chr = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) ; nc += (chr == '\n') ? 0 : 1);
printf("%d\n", nc);
```

or this

```
int chr;
int nc;

for (nc = 0 ; ((chr = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) ; )
{
    if (chr != '\n')
        nc += 1;
}
printf("%d\n", nc);
```

note that `x = (condition) ? value : another_value` is called the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C), and is equivalent to

```
if (condition)
    x = value;
else
    x = another_value;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one equivalent way, although I'm not really happy about having to initialize `c` to `\n`. (the reason for this is that the get_char is performed in the post step:

```
int c, nc;

for (c = '\n', nc = 0; c != EOF; c = getchar()) {
    if (c != '\n')
        ++nc;
    }
}
printf("%d\n", nc);
```

Another way is:

```
int c, nc;
c = getchar();
for (nc = 0; c != EOF; c = getchar()) {
    if (c != '\n')
        ++nc;
    }
}
printf("%d\n", nc);
```

Comment: why did you pose `c = '\n'` in your first statement? did you mean 'c = getchar()`?

Comment: So that it would do nothing the first iteration. A better way is to use `c = getchar()` which I did in the second example.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done as shown below

```
    int nc=0;
    char ch;
    for (; (ch =getchar()) != EOF; )
    {
        if (ch != '\n')
            nc++;
    }

    printf("Count = %d\n",nc);
```

The initialization and increment are not mandatory they can be skipped as shown in the above code.So by doing this we are achieving the same as we do with your `while()` loop

Comment: Your mistake is that you give ready code without explanation to a complete beginnner. That is not the way in which he will learn.
What's the point of copy-pasting?

Comment: @Igor Really !!!!!! ok I take it but I am happy my code is good. Needs explanation :)

Comment: @undur_gongor What is strange here.